# Find two substrings using one regex

Tags: java, regex

External app sends following line:

`U999;U999;$SMS=;client: John Doe; A$ABC12345;,  SHA:12345ABCDE`

I need to extract 2 values from it: John Doe and 12345ABCDE

Now I can extract separately those 2 values using regex:

`(?=client:(.*?);)` for John Doe
`(?=SHA:(.*?)$)` for 12345ABCDE

Is it possible to extract those values using one regex in Pattern and extract them as list of 2 values?

Comment: Use `client:\h*([^;]+);.*\bSHA:\h*([^;]+)` and grab 2 captured values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a pattern matcher with two capture groups:

```java
String input = "U999;U999;$SMS=;client: John Doe; A$ABC12345;,  SHA:12345ABCDE";
String pattern = "^.*;\\s*client: ([^;]+);.*;.*\\bSHA:([^;]+).*$";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = r.matcher(input);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println("client: " + m.group(1));
    System.out.println("SHA:    " + m.group(2));
}
```

This prints:

```
client: John Doe
SHA:    12345ABCDE
```